# What is the proper way to "append" VUE component to DOM using my filtered data from ajax, in laravel?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, vue.js, components

i'm new here so hope everything is ok.

I'm building a search filter with ajax, using a proper controller for filtering my data and send the result to ajax.
At this point i would like to "append" my vue component and bind the data result.

Searching on google this is the "wrong" way, because js and vue.js use different methods to render to DOM.(right?)

I found that the correct way, could be send the results data from ajax (in some way) to my vue component.
How can i do this, in laravel?

app.js :

```
 Vue.component('template', require('./components/template.vue').default;

const app = new Vue({
 el:'#mytemplate',
});
```

template.vue :

```
  <template>
     <div>{{ title }}</div>
  </template>

 <script>
    export default{
     props:['title'],
    }
</script>
```

my ajax:

```
  success: function(data){
   for(var i = 0; i < 10;i++){
      name = data[i];

    //what i would is 
    // $('#template').empty();
    //$('#template').append('<template title="'+ name +'"></template>');

   }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance at all!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Vue template, perform an ajax request on the mounted hook to fetch data and bind it to the title data object instead of a prop

You can have the Vue component always present in your Blade view file and rendered or shown conditionally when the data loads

Something like this should work

`template.vue`

```
<template>
  <div v-show="shown">
    <div v-for="title in titles" :key="title">
      {{ title }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
       data() {
         return {
           shown: false,
           titles: [],
         }
       },
        mounted() {
            axios.get('/route').then(response => {
              this.titles = response.data;
              this.shown = true;
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You don't have to wait your component to be mounted to start fetching the data. Instead, fetch your data once your component is created in 'created()' hook.

Comment: @Sackey that would defeat the whole purpose of Ajax then wouldn't it? Why not just pass the data from the Blade template to the component as a prop then?